# How to escape "<CR>" in a mapping in vimscript

Tags: vim

I want to construct a command line within a mapping, using the `:execute normal "commandstring"` techinique. But I can't do it from within a mapping as vim immediately interprets the "" as a keypress. So this doesn't work:

```
nnoremap <leader>jj :execute "normal :tabnew foo.txt\<cr>"<cr>
```

I tried doubly escaping the backslash, to no effect:

```
nnoremap <leader>jj :execute "normal :tabnew foo.txt\\<cr>"<cr>
```

Now vim types in the backslash and then interprets the  as a keypress.

Any way out of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's indeed tricky. You have to escape the `<` character as `<lt>`, so that the `<cr>` is not parsed as special key notation:

```
nnoremap <leader>jj :execute "normal :tabnew foo.txt\<lt>cr>"<cr>
```

---

Note that your example doesn't need any of this; `:normal :...<CR>` is the same as `...`

```
nnoremap <leader>jj :tabnew foo.txt<cr>
```

Comment: Thank you. The example indeed doesn't need execute as it is a simplified case. The actual mapping does some string concatenation and a call to substitute().